# Performance bottleneck in concurrent calls to System.currentTimeInMillis()

Tags: java, concurrency, clojure

I suspect that calls from separate threads (>15) are having a negative effect on performance.  Is there a better way to get at the system time in concurrent applications?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, most OSes provide good support for this kind of function and it is probably implemented as a native method. Why are you blaming this method for your performance problems?

Comment: What profiling have you done that shows that this function is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little tip:

I read from google engineers and other programmers that it is better to use System.nanotime. For example [joshua bloch](http://www.techper.net/2008/08/10/systemcurrenttimemillis-systemnanotime-and-their-resolution/)

> For interval timing, always use System.nanoTime in preference to
>   System.currentTimeMillis

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Also, even according to your quote, System.nanoTime is preferred for interval timing, there is no mention of what the OP is using system time for. Interval timing may not be applicable here.

Comment: Maybe it does not answer the question directly, but I think already others answered the question so I was only providing a tip I read.

Comment: http://www.techper.net/2008/08/10/systemcurrenttimemillis-systemnanotime-and-their-resolution/

timeinMillis has problems with MS windows' granularity

Comment: Thanks for the link Gene T :). Know we know a little better why currentMillis could be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

If it really is a problem, you can have a background thread store the current time in a `volatile`. Or just call it less often.

Comment: +1 - there is definitely something a bit weird about an application which has to make frequent calls to `System.currentTimeMillis`.